# How to change server name in SQL Server connection options?

Tags: sql-server

I have two servers the first one have an IP: 10.10.10.1 and SQL Server installed on it .

I want to connect to another SQL Server database at IP: 10.10.10.2 from 10.10.10.1 but I can't change the servername option, it always shows the 10.10.10.1 server name, and I can't change it.

I need to change it to 10.10.10.2 so I can connect to the database.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running SSMS as administrator?

Comment: Have you tried typing in the textbox server name?